# How could I enable cursor line only for gvim?

Tags: vim

I want to enable `cursorline` only for gvim but disable it for vim in TUI, I tried this in `.vimrc`

```
if has("gui_running")
    set cul
else
    set nocul
endif
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What does `:verbose set cursorline?` say?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on vim stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.vimrc` gets read by gvim and vim while the `.gvimrc` gets only read by gvim. As the docs say:

> The gvimrc file is where GUI-specific startup commands should be placed.  It
>   is always sourced after the |vimrc| file.  If you have one then the $MYGVIMRC
>   environment variable has its name.

While your command *should* do the trick, I'd place the `set cul` command in my `.gvimrc`.

This will also help your `.vimrc` being cleaner and you don't need `gui_running` checks anymore.

Comment: I believe that .vimrc gets read by gvim if there's no .gvimrc

Comment: @NathanFellman: `.vimrc` gets ALWAYS read by gvim; updated answer.

Comment: @eckes: I tried to put `set cul` only in `.vimrc`, now for normal text files, I don't have cursorline highlighted, bug for `.bashrc` and `.vimrc`， cursor line is still highlighted, is there any special for these two file?

Comment: @Alaya: not that I would know. Sorry.